# Required rights to start crawl

Tags: powershell, search, permissions, crawl

Boss wants to start/stop a specific crawl remotely.

Thought about using a `pssession cmdlet` to test.

However, I want to use a specific account to do so, with just enough rights to to start and stop the crawl I need.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible unless you build some service in between. If you have search admin rights you have rights to all crawls set up.

Alternatively you could set up another search service application and give him access only to this one (that is done via CA)

One option (for service in between) would be to create an console or forms application with (2 options) start stop that would do what you need and then you can store credentials in the windows cred store.